# How fast would i have to travel for time to appear frozen?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, time, inertial-frames, observers

i have to make a school project about something that interests me. so i thought about this question. if anyone could answer me, that would be nice :)
(sorry if my English is bad) 
also im wondering what kinds of damage that would inflict

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are simply moving fast, that is, you have already accelerated to your final speed, time would never appear frozen.  Your experience would be no different than when you are at rest.  There would be no damage (provided you didn't cause any during acceleration).  Your experience would be exactly the same as if you are at rest.

This is one of the fundamental features of the principle of relativity. You would be living in an inertial frame of reference, and  in your frame you are at rest.   Nature and the laws of physics are the same in any inertial frame of reference.  In fact, there's no fundamental way of determining whether *you* are moving and the rest of the universe is at rest, or if *everything else* is moving and *you* are at rest.

Comment: I’ve always had a follow-up question that is: Will I who suppose is moving at 0.9c relative to an observer. Then what will **I** observe different for that observer (apart from them also moving relative to me at 0.9c).